# Turbo sort - Time Limit Exceeded

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Am trying to solve a Codechef problem ([Turbo Sort](http://www.codechef.com/problems/TSORT)). The problem is

> Given the list of numbers, you are to sort them in non decreasing
>   order.
>
> #### Input
>
> t – the number of numbers in list, then t lines follow [t <= 10^6].
>
> Each line contains one integer: N [0 <= N <= 10^6]
>
> #### Output
>
> Output given numbers in non decreasing order.
>
> #### Example
>
> Input:
>
> 5 5 3 6 7 1
>
> Output:
>
> 1 3 5 6 7

My Solution is :

```
l = []
t = input()
MAX = 10**6
while t <= MAX and t != 0:
    n = input()
    l.append(n)
    t = t - 1
st = sorted(l)
for x in st:
    print x
```

The challenge is this program should run in 5 sec. When i submit the file, codechef says it is exceeding the time and needs optimization.

Can some one help, how to optimize it ?

Comment: does `input()` work? I don't think it works

Comment: @AswinMurugesh It works for numbers because Python can just interpret them; you shouldn’t use `input` though.

Comment: @poke: no when a series of numbers are given in a single line, wont there be a problem using `input()`?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh Yes, on a single line, but the problem description says it’s one number per line.

Comment: @poke: ok. saw that just now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My accepted solutions:

```
import sys
from itertools import imap
T = int(raw_input())
lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
lis = imap(str, sorted(imap(int, lines)))
print "\n".join(lis)
```

A readable version(accepted solution) :

```
import sys
T = raw_input()           
lines = sys.stdin.readlines() #fetch all lines from the STDIN
lines.sort(key=int)           #sort the list in-place(faster than sorted) 
print "\n".join(lines)        #use `str.join` instead of a for-loop
```

Comment: Seems a bit wasteful to go through the trouble of `imap` just to use `.join`. Why not just loop over the list and print each element? Also, is `readlines()` allowed? Since the user has to explicitly end the reading by sending an EOF, as opposed to simply entering a certain number of inputs.

Comment: @arshajii Yes `sys.stdin` works fine on codechef. I tried both of the solutions with for-loop but got TLE.

Comment: That's interesting, I would have thought the opposite. +1 Anyway

Answer (score 2):

Things like readlines should be supported. I've just made an attempt and got this as an accepted solution:

```
import sys
print '\n'.join(map(str, sorted(map(int, sys.stdin.read().split()[1:]))))
```

Not pretty but functional. Took me a bit before I figured out you had to skip the first number, debugging is a bit annoying with this system ;)