# Is there a more efficient way to sort a list than list.sort() in Python?

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to solve a challenge on Codechef.com to sort a large list within a certain time limit. I've tried using the builtin `list.sort()` and my own function, but when I upload the code it always shows "Time limit exceeded". Is there more efficient way than using `list.sort()` in terms of runtime?

Question:

- Given the list of numbers, you are to sort them in non decreasing order.
- Input

  - t – the number of numbers in list, then t lines follow [t <= 10^6].
  - Each line contains one integer: N [0 <= N <= 10^6]
- Output

  - Output given numbers in non decreasing order.

My answer:

```
test_cases = int(input())
store = []
count = 0
while count < test_cases:
    i = int(input())
    store.append(i)
    count += 1
store.sort()
for each_item in store:
    print(each_item)
```

Comment: Did you use `list.sort` or `sorted`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to sort 1M records in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180240/best-way-to-sort-1m-records-in-python) or look for instance at http://neopythonic.blogspot.de/2008/10/sorting-million-32-bit-integers-in-2mb.html

Comment: Are you sure that the sorting is the problem? From the little information I have, it seems more likely you're just generating too much data to properly process in the time limit, or exceed the time limit before you even reach the sorting step.

Comment: @delnan i am not sure what the problem exactly is ., but i need a program which does this in least time. Thanks for all your quick responses

Comment: If you use the term *efficient*, please define what you mean by it. Efficient in terms of computation time, memory usage, disk usage, ...?

Comment: @user2968894 Then sorting is not the issue here. You should add the problem description and your attempt in the question body.

Comment: i've edited the question and made it clear

Comment: dont use python sort for a very large number of integer, Python sort is called tim sort, its a fusion version or merge sort and insertion sort. So, i think the best for you is radix sort. Check this http://www.geekviewpoint.com/python/sorting/radixsort

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turbo sort - Time Limit Exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430539/turbo-sort-time-limit-exceeded)

Comment: Thank you very much @ Ashwini chowdhary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## theory

Actually due to the data limitations (integer of maximum value 10^6) the most efficient is to use **count sort** (bucket sort) due to its linear complexity, not the `sorted` or `.sort` (which are O(nlogn))

Obviously, it is true for big amount of numbers (of similar row of magnitude). if `t` is **much** smaller than the maximum value, than it (empirically) be better to use the O(nlogn) approach.

So:

- from the complexity point of view: it is preferable to use count sort, which is O(max(M,n)) where M is the maximum value and n is the number of test cases
- for small test cases it may be better to use the built-in `sorted` which is O(nlogn) where n is the number of samples

## evaluation

I performed very simple testing on random arrays, showing how (naively implemented) countsort performs as compared to heavily optimised Timsort on bounded data

```
from timeit import Timer as T
import random

def timsort(x):
    return sorted(x)

def countsort(x):
    m = max(x)
    buckets = [0] * (m+1)
    for a in x: buckets[a] += 1
    return [ b for c in ( [a] * buckets[a] for a in xrange(m+1) ) for b in c ]


for t,n in [ (1000,1000), (1000,10000), (10000,10000), (10000,100000), (100000,100000), (100000,1000000) ]:

    print 't=',t,'n=',n

    X = [ random.randint(0,t) for _ in xrange(n) ]

    t = T( lambda: countsort(X) )
    print 'count',t.timeit(number=1000)

    t = T( lambda: timsort(X) )
    print 'timso',t.timeit(number=1000)
```

results:

```
t= 1000 n= 1000
count 0.759298086166
timso 0.296448945999
t= 1000 n= 10000
count 2.71147489548
timso 3.95411610603
t= 10000 n= 10000
count 7.57060909271
timso 4.03612089157
t= 10000 n= 100000
count 28.043751955
timso 59.6779661179
t= 100000 n= 100000
count 78.1641709805
timso 58.4075620174
t= 100000 n= 1000000
count 286.381267071
timso 1023.59388494
```

So it seems, that if `n>10t` (where `t` is a maximum value) then countsort is much faster. Otherwise, better implementation of Timsort outperforms better complexity.

Comment: You'll have a hard time beating a hand-tuned Timsort written in C when the alternative is written in Python, even if it has asymptotically better complexity.

Comment: @delnan might be right. The log(n) factors only gets you a lead of 13.8(assuming natural log). Timsort's constant factors might be better.

Comment: I implemented counting sort, Timsort beats it by 0.34 seconds. My implementation is posted as a separate answer. It could be improved upon by some of you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You will find my comment below Iejlot's answer that Timsort beats my implementation of counting sort, although barely. I am submitting it here for anyone to improve upon it.

```
d={}
newlist=[]
for i in original_List:
      try:
            d[i]+=1
      except:
            d[i]=1
for x,y in d.items():
      newlist+=[x for t in range(y)]
```